# Spring i18n localization from multiple propertie files

Tags: java, spring, maven, internationalization

I have two projects: A and B. A use B functionality so B is added as maven dependency to A. In B I have next locale.xml file:

> ```
> > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <beans
> > xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
> > xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> >        xsi:schemaLocation="
> >        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
> >        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd ">
> > 
> >     <!-- ******************** -->
> >     <!-- Internationalization -->
> >     <!-- ******************** -->
> >     <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
> >         <property name="basenames">
> >             <list>
> >                 <value>/META-INF/i18n/messages</value>
> >             </list>
> >         </property>
> >         <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
> >         <property name="cacheSeconds" value="1"/>
> >     </bean> </beans>
> ```

In A I have folder /META-INF/i18n/ with my prop files and I use this files but also I need use prop files from project B. The main question: **How can I use both props files from A and B in project A with minimum changes ?**

Answer (score 1):

Add /META-INF/ of project B in the list of sources for project A

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible ways to resolve your problems.

I assume both projects are under your control.

Option 1. Copy over the properties files from B's location to A's location during build time. I believe it is possible with Maven, certainly it is super-easy with Gradle...
I don't like this idea very much, but it should work.

Option 2. Create a project C as a shared dependency between A and B that will provide required MessageSource Bean to your projects. This is more elegant solution than option 1, but requires additional dependency.

Option 3. The problem you've mentioned suggest that there is something wrong with your design. Actually, you should not ever require reading from dependency's resources. The dependency should provide you with appropriately translated messages (that usually requires passing the Locale in this way or another). If you happen to have many common messages, than it make sense to move them into shared resource files and copy them to appropriate places at build time. But please make sure that these messages are really common, that is you are not using the same messages in different context (for example the same text on a button and in window title will be translated in a different way in many languages).
So this option is, try analyzing whether design is correct and fix underlying problems.